# Error accepting android licenses on mac. Trying to set up for Flutter development on Mac

Tags: java, flutter, android-sdk-tools

I am following the start up [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path) here to set up Flutter on Mac.

I get the following from running `flutter doctor`

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale
    en)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
      more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

When I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` I get the following:

```
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run
(/Users/mia/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager): "exited
code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
detailed instructions.
```

I have tried re-installing and updating the Android SDK through android studio multiple times. I also tried updating my path to Java and installing a new JDK. This is in my .zshrc

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home`

This is the output of flutter doctor --android-licenses --vv

```
[   +2 ms] Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run
           (/Users/mia/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager):
"exited
           code 1".
           Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
           visit
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
           detailed instructions.
[   +1 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      AndroidLicenseValidator.runLicenseManager
           (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:406:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      DoctorCommand.runCommand
           (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:49:26)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1297:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      CommandRunner.runCommand
(package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:339:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:285:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:115:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +255 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 252ms
[        ] Running 0 shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

I have MacOS Sonoma and a M1 mac I installed java jdk 21.